# C++ - String with Depth

Tags: c++, string

I want to reverse a string that betweer character `(` and `)`
If there a string between it, it will be reverse
For example:
`(abcde)` will be `edcba`

The problem is, how about the string like this:
`Ab(cde) (Ab (Cdef))` will be `Abedc Cdef bA`

Here is my code that string is between a single `(` and `)`:

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string str;
    string rev="";

    cin>>str;
    for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i++){
        if(str[i]=='('){
            for(int j=i+1; str[j]!=')'; j++){
                rev += str[j];
            }
        }
    }
    reverse(rev.begin(), rev.end());
    cout<<rev<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here is the general idea: you need to maintain a stack in your program. When you see a `(`, you add the letters into a new list and push the list to the top of the stack. When you see a `)`, you pop the list off the slack and reverse characters in the list.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to work this out with pencil and paper first?  The code you're showing us is a solution to a different, i.e. easier problem.

Comment: Recursion? When you see '(' result string += <function_name>